# TextView as attribute?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to use my TextView as attribute

```
private TextView up = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_up);
private TextView mid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_mid);
private TextView down = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_down);
```

instead of define it evertime new:

```
public void onButtonClickUp(View v) {
        TextView up = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_up);
        TextView mid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_mid);
        TextView down = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_down);
        <..>
}

public void onButtonClickDown(View v) {
        TextView up = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_up);
        TextView mid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_mid);
        TextView down = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_down);
        <..>
}
```

The upper methode is producing a `force close error` on my android device. How to solve this or is that generally possible?

Thanks!

Comment: you can declare Textview as global variable just after class declaration.So that you can use it inside the whole class.If it's set public static the textview can be used in other activities to get its value.

Comment: I highly recommend to not declare variables global for this usecase. Global variables should just be used very carefully.

Comment: @ceekay I tried to convey the same idea of the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView up;
    private TextView mid;
    private TextView down;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     up = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_up);
     mid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_mid);
     down = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_down);

}
```

I'm not sure why your app is crashing, but you will save yourself a lot of headache by declaring/assigning your widgets like this... only one time for the whole activity.